# remove this child and add new child AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, movieclip, removechild, addchild

i've been stuck on this for quite a while, 
i'm working with a Main.as and LivrmScreen.as 
and basically LivrmScreen.as is a game screen with other movieclip actions going on...
then i have a button on LivrmScreen that i wish to remove LivrmScreen itself and show homeScreen (all the homeScreen functions are in Main.as)

```
var homeScreen: HomeScreen;
public function LivrmScreen() {

        backhomeBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onBackhomeBtnClicked);

    }
function onBackhomeBtnClicked(evt:MouseEvent) {

        homeScreen = new HomeScreen();


        stage.addChild(homeScreen);
        parent.removeChild(this);

    }
```

this is what i have right now, 
i added parent.removeChild because it won't remove when it is just removeChild ...
and because of that i added stage.addChild so that home screen will show up properly.

**but then when homeScreen shows up the button's don't actually work ... so its just showing a dead movieclip. why is that???**

i also tried to put the onBackhomeBtnClicked function in main.as thinking so that all the homeScreen functions are there and maybe the buttons will work... but in that case i cant even get the screens to remove and add properly

Comment: Where are you adding `LivrmScreen`? That is, what is the parent of `LivrmScreen`?

Answer (score 1):

There's a flaw in your code logics. I don't want to go too deep into the OOP principles or tell you to use frameworks that takes care of these kind of things.

Here's a cheap and fast way out:

in Main.as

```
private function goToLivrScreen(e:Event = null):void
{
    var livrScreen:LivrScreen = new LivrScreen();
    livrScreen.addEventListener("onClose", onLivrScreenClose);
    addChild(livrScreen);
}
private function onLivrScreenClose(e:Event = null):void
{
    removeChild(e.currentTarget as DisplayObject);
    // add code to show main menu or whatever you wanted
}
```

in LivrScreen.as

```
backhomeBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onBackhomeBtnClicked);
```

and handler

```
private function onBackhomeBtnClicked(evt:MouseEvent):void
{
    // remove all listeners from all object that you have so your LivrScreen could be garbage collected
    // when done just dispatch the Event that Main.as is waiting for
    dispatchEvent(new Event("onClose"));
}
```

This is a pretty crude way to do it and there can be many improvements, but it will make your code a little cleaner and hopefully, more scalable in case you want to add new screen or change some implementation.

Comment: if this answers your question, please mark the question as answered and vote it up so others with same problem could see the solution. Glad I could help, good luck ;)